# How can I sort, insert in between and update full dataset in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I have a few issues with chartjs which simple update method won't solve.

I wonder if there is an option to:

1. painlessly sort the datasets;
2. insert some data in between two points;
3. reload the whole chart without replacing the canvas with a
   completely new chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option built in, but it is pretty easy to write your own using the `addData`, `removeData` methods that Chart.js provides.

```
var MyBarChartMethods = {
    // sort a dataset
    sort: function (chart, datasetIndex) {
        var data = []
        chart.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar, j) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    data.push({
                        label: chart.scale.xLabels[j],
                        values: [bar.value]
                    })
                } else 
                    data[j].values.push(bar.value)
            });
        })

        data.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.values[datasetIndex] > b.values[datasetIndex])
                return -1;
            else if (a.values[datasetIndex] < b.values[datasetIndex])
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        })

        chart.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar, j) {
                if (i === 0)
                    chart.scale.xLabels[j] = data[j].label;
                bar.label = data[j].label;
                bar.value = data[j].values[i];
            })
        });
        chart.update();
    },
    // reload data
    reload: function (chart, datasetIndex, labels, values) {
        var diff = chart.datasets[datasetIndex].bars.length - values.length;
        if (diff < 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < -diff; i++)
                chart.addData([0], "");
        } else if (diff > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++)
                chart.removeData();
        }

        chart.datasets[datasetIndex].bars.forEach(function (bar, i) {
            chart.scale.xLabels[i] = labels[i];
            bar.value = values[i];
        })
        chart.update();
    }
}
```

which you call like so (where myBarChart is your chart)

```
// sort
MyBarChartMethods.sort(myBarChart, 0)
// reload - same number of values
MyBarChartMethods.reload(myBarChart, 0, ["J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
// reload - more values
MyBarChartMethods.reload(myBarChart, 0, ["J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
// reload - less values
MyBarChartMethods.reload(myBarChart, 0, ["J", "F", "M", "A", "M"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Inserting 2 points is special case of reload, so you can use the same function (or write your own based on that easily)

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lkdxxkfa/

Comment: This seems not working correctly, if you are using more than one dataset.

Comment: @Joko - do you have a fiddle for the case that fails? Thanks!

Comment: @potatopeelings - I modified your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yscmsa0r/1/ only one dataset will be sorted, and the bars of the other one don't change. This makes no sense, because after the sorting, the month won't be correct for the other dataset anymore.

Comment: @Joko - thanks mate! I've updated the answer and the fiddle - here's the modified version of the above fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jzezwu7u/

Comment: No worries. Give a holler if you find something else that's broken.

Answer (score 1):

I came to stackoverflow having the same question so what I have done is created a plugin that allows you to add a sort function to ChartJS

https://github.com/scotthsieh0503/chartjs-plugin-sort

it also allows you to pass in a 'pre-sorted' array as a reference for sorting

Comment: I think I need a working example of how to use this, can't make it work..

Comment: Agreed especially the reference