# Chartjs bar order adjustment after bar chart is drawn

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In the [chartjs document](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-prototype-methods), you can use update() method to redraw bar the value change, but not the bar label change, or bar order change.

What I want to do is to sort the bar order by label after new bar is added to chart by myBarChart.addData().

Here is my attempt to solve the problem which fails:

```
        this.myBarChart.addData([1], tickString);
        // TODO: need to sort here by tick string when adding new one!
        this.myBarChart.datasets[0].bars = _.sortBy(bars, function(bar){

            return parseFloat(bar.label); // label example: '1.223', '1.44'
        });
```

**Question**:
If possible, how to sort bar by label for a chartjs chart after bar chart is drawn?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it with a separate function. Adapted from [How can I sort, insert in between and update full dataset in chartjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399991)

```
var MyBarChartMethods = {
    // sort a dataset
    sortByLabel: function (chart) {
        // get data from chart elements (instead of messing up the actual data object)
        var data = []
        chart.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar, j) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    data.push({
                        label: parseFloat(chart.scale.xLabels[j]),
                        values: [bar.value]
                    })
                } else
                    data[j].values.push(bar.value)
            });
        })

        // sort the data based on label
        data.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.label > b.label)
                return 1;
            else if (a.label < b.label)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        })

        // update the chart elements using the sorted data
        chart.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar, j) {
                if (i === 0)
                    chart.scale.xLabels[j] = data[j].label;
                bar.label = data[j].label;
                bar.value = data[j].values[i];
            })
        });
        chart.update();
    },
}
```

and you call it thus

```
MyBarChartMethods.sortByLabel(myBarChart)
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jk1k0g5u/