# How to Sort a Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart JS (with Logarithmic Scales)

Tags: javascript, sorting, chart.js

I've been scearching for a way of sorting value with 'Chart JS'.

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910960/chartjs-bar-order-adjustment-after-bar-chart-is-drawn/) and [another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399991/how-can-i-sort-insert-in-between-and-update-full-dataset-in-chartjs) I've founded but this not what I wanted to do.

In fact, by 'sorting' values, I mean something like change the way Chart JS display the colored bar. Because they are always showed in the same order of color, and this is what I want to change.

Here's a screen of [what I've made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwVZ8.png) but, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgUtS.png)
(when I 'cross' a type of data ), It reveals there was values not apparents because of the Logarithmic scale. But I really need this type of scales due to the type of values.

So, if I could change the order of the colored bar "in ascending" (not sure how to say that....), then the scale will not be able to hide values.

I hope you guys could help me, I'll stay here if you have questions.

Thanks :)

PS: Here's my code :

```
    // Somewhere
```

`var response = [
["Stand 1", "Stand 2","Stand 3", "Stand 4", "Stand 5"],//nb elements dans les 5 tableaux
["1", "15", "1", "1", "20000"],
["10", "10", "10", "10000", "5"],
["5", "5", "50000", "5", "10"],
["500000", "5", "5", "5", "10"],
];
obj.dom.find(".widget_content").html('<canvas id="graph" height="'+obj.hauteur+'"></canvas>');//resize la hauteur du widget
obj.showGraph(obj.dom.find("#graph"), response); // Affichage du graphe avec les données

//Somewhere Else
this.showGraph = function(canvas, paramDataOccupation)
{
// Initialisation
// Convertion des valeurs en int
// commence a 1 car 0 = description des labels
var dataOccupation = new Array(nbInfo-1);
for (l = 1; l < nbInfo ; l++){
dataOccupation[l-1] = new Array(nbServeur);//nouveau tableau dans le tableau
for (m = 0; m < nbServeur ; m++){
var recup = parseInt(paramDataOccupation[l][m]);
dataOccupation[l-1][m] = recup;
}
}

var obj = this;
//! Configuration du graphique
var largeurWidget = this.dom.width();
canvas.width(largeurWidget);

var datasetChart = {
labels: paramDataOccupation[0],//nom dans l'axe Y (Partenaire)
// Les données d'occupation
datasets: [ 
{ //Erreurs
data: dataOccupation[0],
label: "C",
backgroudColor: obj.color1,
stack: 1,
},
{ // Suspendues
data: dataOccupation[1],
label: "D",
backgroundColor: obj.color2,
stack: 1,
},
{ // ATraiter
data: dataOccupation[2],
label: "A",
backgroundColor: obj.color3,
stack: 1,
},
{ // AExploiter
data: dataOccupation[3],
label: "B",
backgroundColor: obj.color4,
stack: 1,
}
],
};

//! Affichage du graphique
var myLineChart = new Chart(canvas, {
name: "Titre",
type: 'horizontalBar',
data: datasetChart,
toolTip: {
shared: true
},
options: {
scales: {
xAxes: [{
type: 'logarithmic',
position: 'bottom',
stacked: true,
ticks: {
min: 1,
autoSkip: false,//affiche toutes les barres intermediaires (facilite la lecture)
callback: function(label) {
//On affiche uniquement les palier de 10exp(n)
//c'est un peu bricole mais je doute qu'il y est plus de 1.000.000.000.000 de remises par Partenaires
var tableau = [1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,10000000000,100000000000,1000000000000];
if(tableau.includes(label)){
if(label == 1)
return '0';//contourne le probleme de log(0) impossible
else
return (new Number(label)).toLocaleString();
}else{
return "";
}
},
maxTicksLimit: 100,//limite du nombre de barres intermediares (cf: autoSkip)
beginAtZero:true,
},
}],//xAxes
yAxes: [{
scaleLabel: {
display: true,
labelString: "Description"
}
}]//yAxes
},
tooltips: {
display: false,
}
},//fin options
showTooltips: false,
onAnimationComplete: function () {

var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
ctx.font = this.scale.font;
ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y);
});
})
}
});`

> Post Editing 1°

Thanks #jordanwillis for your reply !

Well I think about something like that (http s://i.stack.imgur.com/24yNo.png) (only take a look at the "Stand 4" stack) , but as you can see the 'red' bar is always on the 4th position. But I expected the red Bar could be on the 1st position if the value it represent is the biggest. And then to do that for each bar of each stacks.
Let me know if yout want me to do a little of 'paint modification' to give you an exact example of my expectation if I'm not enough accurate.

*(sorry for the bad link but I've not yet reach the 10 reputation points :/)*

Comment: Can you explain how you are wanting your "crossed" out dataset picture to look? I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks #jordanwillis for your reply ! I've add some information by editing my post (not sure if this is the way it must be done but I don't know how to add picture link in a comment (sorry, I'm new here)

Comment: So basically you want your datasets to always be sorted so that the largest values are first and so on? For example, on the first row the blue would be first and the third row the light blue first?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do :)

Comment: Ok, let me see if i can come up with a solution.